# pthread_cond_signal and possible thread starvation

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

If more then one thread waits on a condition variable, what is the order of waking on a pthread_cond_signal. I have read that pthread_cond_signal does not necessarily wake up in order of sleeping. So this may cause starvation...is it not?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's determined by the scheduling policy, which is supposed to be fair.

If the threads are not starved by scheduling - they shouldn't be by this either.

From the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_cond_signal.html):

> If more than one thread is blocked on a condition variable, the scheduling policy determines the order in which threads are unblocked.

Comment: thanks...how do i find the scheduling policy used. by default the thread with the highest priority is woken but if all threads have same..guess its uncertain.

Comment: @Juggler - that's part of the OS kernel, and usually scheduling algorithms are not as simple as you just described, and include means to ensure fairness. Unless you wrote a scheduling algorithm on your own, I would assume it to be fair, that's the basic requirement for scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

Fairness is not guaranteed so starvation is always possible.
To ensure absolute fairness, you would need to implement your own mechanism using a queue to keep track of the order of arrivals.

Answer (score 0):

This question suggests abuse of a condition variable. The use of a condition variable is to alert a thread that a condition has occurred. When you wake only one thread, it must be because **any** thread can service the condition. If you care which thread wakes, then it is not the case that any thread can service the condition.

While you will probably get you what you want on most implementations, there is probably a better way to do whatever it is you are trying to do.